# How do I take a photo and save to microSD card while streaming video on ESP32-CAM

Tags: video-streaming, photo, esp32, fat32

I am using an ESP32-CAM to stream video to a web address.  This works fine.  I would like to take a photo if possible while streaming and save it to the onboard micro SD card.

Here is my code for the streaming video.

```
#include "src/OV2640.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "FS.h"                // SD Card ESP32
#include "SD_MMC.h"            // SD Card ESP32
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER

#include "camera_pins.h"

OV2640 cam;

WebServer server(81);
//Stream server(81);

const char HEADER[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" \
                      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n" \
                      "Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=123456789000000000000987654321\r\n";
const char BOUNDARY[] = "\r\n--123456789000000000000987654321\r\n";
const char CTNTTYPE[] = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: ";
const int hdrLen = strlen(HEADER);
const int bdrLen = strlen(BOUNDARY);
const int cntLen = strlen(CTNTTYPE);

void handle_jpg_stream(void)
{
  char buf[32];
  int s;

  WiFiClient client = server.client();

  client.write(HEADER, hdrLen);
  client.write(BOUNDARY, bdrLen);

  while (true)
  {
    if (!client.connected()) break;
    cam.run();
    s = cam.getSize();
    client.write(CTNTTYPE, cntLen);
    sprintf( buf, "%d\r\n\r\n", s );
    client.write(buf, strlen(buf));
    client.write((char *)cam.getfb(), s);
    client.write(BOUNDARY, bdrLen);
  }
}

const char JHEADER[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" \
                       "Content-disposition: inline; filename=capture.jpg\r\n" \
                       "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";
const int jhdLen = strlen(JHEADER);

void handle_jpg(void)
{
  WiFiClient client = server.client();

  cam.run();
  if (!client.connected()) return;

  client.write(JHEADER, jhdLen);
  client.write((char *)cam.getfb(), cam.getSize());
  
}

void handleNotFound()
{
  String message = "Server is running!\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  server.send(200, "text / plain", message);
}

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);

 camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;

  // Frame parameters
  //  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_VGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 12;
  config.fb_count = 2;

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
#endif

  cam.init(config);

  IPAddress ip;

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssidString, pskString);
  
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(F("."));
  }
  ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.println(F("WiFi connected"));
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println(ip);
  Serial.print("Stream Link: http://");
  Serial.print(ip);
  Serial.println("/mjpegd/1");
  server.on("/XXXXXXX/1", HTTP_GET, handle_jpg_stream);
  server.on("/jpg", HTTP_GET, handle_jpg);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin();
 
}

void loop()
{ 
 server.handleClient();
 
}
```

Once this starts up and connects to the Wi-Fi I can log onto the web address and see the stream.

Next I want to capture a still photo if an event happens like a pin going high.

Something like

```
int motion = 16;
int name = 0;

void loop(){ 
 long state = digitalRead(motion);
  if(state == HIGH) {
name = name + 1;
if(!SD_MMC.begin()){
  Serial.println("SD Card Mount Failed");
  return;
}
 
uint8_t cardType = SD_MMC.cardType();
if(cardType == CARD_NONE){
  Serial.println("No SD Card attached");
  return;
}

camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;

// Take Picture with Camera
fb = esp_camera_fb_get();  
if(!fb) {
  Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
  return;
}

String path = "/picture" + String(name) +".jpg";

  fs::FS &fs = SD_MMC; 
  Serial.printf("Picture file name: %s\n", path.c_str());
  
  File file = fs.open(path.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
  if(!file){
    Serial.println("Failed to open file in writing mode");
  } 
  else {
    file.write(fb->buf, fb->len); // payload (image), payload length
    Serial.printf("Saved file to path: %s\n", path.c_str());
   
  }
  file.close();
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb); 

 }
 else{
  
 }

 server.handleClient();
}
```

My esp8266-12e code

```
int MOVEMENT = 5;

void setup() {

pinMode(MOVEMENT,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(MOVEMENT,LOW);
}

void loop() {

 long state = digitalRead(LED2);
  if(state == HIGH) {
  
digitalWrite(MOVEMENT,HIGH);
delay(500);
digitalWrite(MOVEMENT,LOW);
}
}
```

Can I make pin GPIO5 an OUTPUT pin like this and make it work?

I have tried this but to no avail.  Any ideas of how I can do this.

Comment: What does “to no avail” mean? Specifically what goes wrong? Does the code not compile? Does it crash? Is the saved photo corrupt?

Comment: In addition, please add the console output of the program.

Comment: So I have put a pull-down resister on pin 16 (motion) and set it to pinMode(motion,INPUT); because I was getting a HIGH reading all the time.  Now though I am not getting a HIGH reading from Pin GPIO5 on my ESP8266-12e.  I have edited my post in include its code.